# Run a function with almost similar variables c++

Tags: c++

Assume we have some variables named *var1*, *var2* , ..., *var100*.

How can I call a function named *func()* with that variables with a for loop. I mean how should I 
change this code that it works?

```
for (int counter{1}; counter <= 100; ++counter) {

     cout << func(var+counter);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do that. Why don't you use an array to begin with?

Comment: Why do you have `var1`, `var2`, ..., `var100` instead of an array?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's just a question for me. I wanted to know that is it possible, how? because you know there is no impossible in computer world :D

Comment: Generalizing the above a bit, any time you have sequentially numbered variables you almost certainly want an array or array-like container. If the numbers are not sequential, consider a `std::unordered_map` or a mapping function.

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian It is possible. First you copy the numbered variables into an array, then you process the array.

Comment: If you have guarantees on exactly how the variables are laid out in memory, you may be able to exploit undefined behaviour. If the variables are contiguous in memory and still sequential you can take a pointer to the first variable and increment the pointer to get the next one. This used to be a pretty safe assumption, but computers play really neat games with memory these days.

Comment: c++ is not an interpreted language. So there is no way to use run time variables to build variable names later and access the content of them. Such code can be written in some scripting languages but not in c++ nor c.

Comment: `for (const auto& var : {var1, var2 , ..., var100}) { cout << func(var);}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Again I have to write all of the 100 variables by hand!

Comment: You can write the variables using code generator, such as a simple script.

Answer (score 2):

There is no<sup>1</sup> way to do it. Use an array instead.

---

<sub>1</sub>

> you know there is no impossible in computer world :D
>   — OP

If you really want to shoot yourself in the foot, there *is* a way: Boost.Preprocessor.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

// ...

int main()
{
    #define FOO(unused0, index, unused1) cout << func(var##index);
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(101, FOO,)
    #undef FOO
}
```

<sup>(Note that this snippet interacts with `var0`, ... `var100`, not `var1`, ... `var100` you asked for. Changing the first index is left as an exercise to the reader. Hint: it can't be done with `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`, you need a different macro.)</sup>

There are some caveats:

- The amount of variables has to be known at compile-time, and it has to be a preprocessor constant (i.e. `101` verbatim does work, but `const int n = 101;` or even `100+1` do not).
- There is a hard limit on the amount of 'iterations'. (`256` by default, probably can be increased).
- This might increase your build times.